# Getting name of value from namedtuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a module with collection:

```
import collections
named_tuple_sex = collections.namedtuple(
                    'FlightsResultsSorter',
                        ['TotalPriceASC',
                         'TransfersASC',
                         'FlightTimeASC',
                         'DepartureTimeASC',
                         'DepartureTimeDESC',
                         'ArrivalTimeASC',
                         'ArrivalTimeDESC',
                         'Airlines']
                    )
FlightsResultsSorter = named_tuple_sex(
    FlightsResultsSorter('TotalPrice', SortOrder.ASC),
    FlightsResultsSorter('Transfers', SortOrder.ASC),
    FlightsResultsSorter('FlightTime', SortOrder.ASC),
    FlightsResultsSorter('DepartureTime', SortOrder.ASC),
    FlightsResultsSorter('DepartureTime', SortOrder.DESC),
    FlightsResultsSorter('ArrivalTime', SortOrder.ASC),
    FlightsResultsSorter('ArrivalTime', SortOrder.DESC),
    FlightsResultsSorter('Airlines', SortOrder.ASC)
)
```

and in another module, I iterate by this collection and I want to get the name of the item:

```
for x in FlightsResultsSorter:
            self.sort(x)
```

so in the code above, I want instead of `x` (which is an object) to pass, for example, `DepartureTimeASC` or `ArrivalTimeASC`.

How can I get this name?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
from itertools import izip

for x, field in izip(FlightsResultsSorter, named_tuple_sex._fields):
    print x, field
```

You can also use `FlightsResultsSorter._asdict()` to get a dict.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without accessing a private member of the namedtuple?

Comment: these aren't considered private members -- the _ convention is only to avoid collisions with, say, a field called _fields.

Comment: That's not true. Prepending (_field) means it's private. Appending (fields_) is what is used to avoid collisions.

Comment: @YounesEO They're publicly documented and the doc has these forewords *To prevent conflicts with field names, the method and attribute names start with an underscore.* You could say that they're not ideally named and don't abide by the convention, but they're definitely not private.

Answer (score 90):

If you're trying to get the actual names, use the [`_fields`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=_fields#collections.somenamedtuple._fields) attribute:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x, y')
p = Point(x=1, y=2)
for name in Point._fields:
    print(name, getattr(p, name))
```

Comment: Is it recommended to access protected members/functions (ex _fields, _asdict()) of a class?

Comment: For python 3+, use `print(f"{name}: {getattr(p, name)}")`

Comment: @awwwd These are not protected members, they are documented ([`_fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields), [`_asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict)).